# Why would you ever want to disable SSR in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

The question is in the title. I don't see a benefit to ever disabling SSR in SvelteKit, even for SPAs that do all the heavy lifting on the client. If it matters, my SvelteKit webapp uses a REST API on a separate server for data via `fetch`. Am I missing something?

edit: I don't mind downvotes, but if I'm asking an obviously dumb question (which I may very well be), an answer or comment would be great. My goal here is to learn.

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason would be the usage of code/a library that is incompatible with SSR as it needs access to the window. Some of these will already cause errors on `import`. You can work around that by using a dynamic import e.g. in `onMount`, but it might just make more sense to deactivate SSR on such a page.

I could also imagine that the page code could generate huge amounts of HTML which would be less efficient to transmit than just sending the code and generating it on the client, not sure if that is very realistic though.